# Is there a way to add a fragment dynamically to a dialog (not DialogFragment)?

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog with custom view inside it using RelativeLayout. I want to add a fragment to this RelativeLayout. I tried to put the fragment statically and it worked, but I want to add it dynamically as I have some arguments I have to pass first.